# Import large table from website and always grab first row

Tags: google-sheets

I need to import the first row of the table in this website:
http://www.ipeadata.gov.br/ExibeSerie.aspx?serid=40940&module=M

Tried IMPORTDATA and IMPORTHTML (and after would find a way to get the first row) but it exceeds maximum size.

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether the use of the custom function is included in your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about using a custom function created by Google Apps Script? When Google Apps Script is used, the current URL Fetch response size is 50 MB. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) By this, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("http://www.ipeadata.gov.br/ExibeSerie.aspx?serid=40940&module=M")` to a cell. By this, the script is run.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const data = html.match(/<tr id\="grd_DXDataRow0".+?>([\s\S\w]+?)<\/tr>/);
  if (data.length != 2) return "Couldn't get value."
  return [XmlService.parse(`<sample>${data[1].trim()}</sample>`).getRootElement().getChildren().map(e => {
    const v = e.getValue();
    return isNaN(v) ? v : Number(v);
  })];
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is used, the following result can be obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)